# Jssor with jquery only displays first picture

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am trying to use jssor carrousel slidesshow but it only displays the first image. I have seen some people with the same problem and tried their solutions but they don't work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jssor.core.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jssor.utils.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jssor.slider.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jssor.slidershow.js'></script>

    <div class='recent_projects'>
    <div id='slider1_container' style='position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 610px; height: 200px; float: left; padding: 30px 0; overflow:hidden;'> 

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u='slides' style='cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 610px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;'>

        <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/003.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/004.jpg' />
            </div>
        <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/002.jpg' />
            </div>

            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/005.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/006.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/007.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/008.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/009.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/010.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/011.jpg' />
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->
        <style>
            /*
            .jssorb01 div           (normal)
            .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .av           (active)
            .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av {
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: .7;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: #000 1px solid;
            }

            .jssorb01 div {
                background-color: gray;
            }

                .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover {
                    background-color: #d3d3d3;
                }

            .jssorb01 .av {
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover {
                background-color: #555555;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u='navigator' class='jssorb01' style='position: relative; top: 180px; left:390px;'>
<!--bottom: 16px; right: 10px;'-->
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u='prototype' style='POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;'></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 02 css */
            /*
            .jssora02l              (normal)
            .jssora02r              (normal)
            .jssora02l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora02r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora02ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora02rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora02l, .jssora02r, .jssora02ldn, .jssora02rdn
            {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(img/a02.png) no-repeat;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            .jssora02l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
            .jssora02r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
            .jssora02l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
            .jssora02r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
            .jssora02ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
            .jssora02rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u='arrowleft' class='jssora02l' style='width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 73px; left: 8px;'>
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u='arrowright' class='jssora02r' style='width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 73px; right: 8px'>
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a  href='http://www.jssor.com'>slideshow html</a>
    </div>

    <div class='project_content'></div>
   </div>
```

The jssor.slidershow.js file contains the standard jssor code without changes:

```
Query(document).ready(function ($) {
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption.html
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

       $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (Result) {


                       $fotos = lee_template_no_escape("fotos1.txt");

                       $("#HomeImgSliders").append($fotos);

               },

            var _CaptionTransitions = [
            //CLIP|LR
            {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 3, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic },
            //CLIP|TB
            {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 12, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic },

            //ZMF|10
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 },

            //ZML|R
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },
            //ZML|B
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            //ZMS|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            //RTT|10
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //RTTL|R
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },
            //RTTL|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //RTTS|R
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} },
            //RTTS|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} },

            //R|IB
            {$Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },
            //B|IB
            {$Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

        $fotos = lee_template_no_escape("fotos1.txt");
        $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (Result) {


                       var html = "<img u=image src=" + value.ImagePath + "/>";//<-- Image Path/paths comes here Correctly

                       $("#HomeImgSliders").append(html);

                   });


               },

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

        });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: All images are there already. Why use ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
<!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

            var _CaptionTransitions = [
            //CLIP|LR
            {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 3, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic },
            //CLIP|TB
            {$Duration: 900, $Clip: 12, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic },

            //ZMF|10
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 },

            //ZML|R
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },
            //ZML|B
            {$Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            //ZMS|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            //RTT|10
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //RTTL|R
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },
            //RTTL|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //RTTS|R
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} },
            //RTTS|B
            {$Duration: 700, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 1.2} },

            //R|IB
            {$Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },
            //B|IB
            {$Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutBack }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 },

            ];

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

    });
</script>

<div class='recent_projects'>
    <div id='slider1_container' style='position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 610px; height: 200px; float: left; padding: 30px 0; overflow:hidden;'>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u='slides' style='cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 610px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;'>

            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/003.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/004.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/002.jpg' />
            </div>

            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/005.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/006.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/007.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/008.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/009.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/010.jpg' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u='image' src='img/photography/011.jpg' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->
        <style>
                /*
            .jssorb01 div           (normal)
            .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .av           (active)
            .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
                .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av {
                    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                    opacity: .7;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border: #000 1px solid;
                }

                .jssorb01 div {
                    background-color: gray;
                }

                    .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover {
                        background-color: #d3d3d3;
                    }

                .jssorb01 .av {
                    background-color: #fff;
                }

                .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover {
                    background-color: #555555;
                }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u='navigator' class='jssorb01' style='position: relative; top: 180px; left:390px;'>
            <!--bottom: 16px; right: 10px;'-->
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u='prototype' style='POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;'></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
                /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 02 css */
                /*
            .jssora02l              (normal)
            .jssora02r              (normal)
            .jssora02l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora02r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora02ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora02rdn            (mousedown)
            */
                .jssora02l, .jssora02r, .jssora02ldn, .jssora02rdn {
                    position: absolute;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: block;
                    background: url(img/a02.png) no-repeat;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }

                .jssora02l {
                    background-position: -3px -33px;
                }

                .jssora02r {
                    background-position: -63px -33px;
                }

                .jssora02l:hover {
                    background-position: -123px -33px;
                }

                .jssora02r:hover {
                    background-position: -183px -33px;
                }

                .jssora02ldn {
                    background-position: -243px -33px;
                }

                .jssora02rdn {
                    background-position: -303px -33px;
                }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u='arrowleft' class='jssora02l' style='width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 73px; left: 8px;'>
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u='arrowright' class='jssora02r' style='width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 73px; right: 8px'>
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a href='http://www.jssor.com'>slideshow html</a>
    </div>

    <div class='project_content'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed a similar issue and my solution is below.

[Appearance before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uv7D.png)

[Appearance after fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NZJa.png)

The solution is to set css (postion and z-index) of disappearing elements:

`.text-tier {position: relative; z-index: 1;}`